# How to share preferences via NSUserDefaults for command line tools?

Tags: macos, nsuserdefaults

I want a half dozen command line tools (used for testing) to share a bundle ID so they can share a NSUserDefaults and Library/Caches subfolder. I could get around the Library/Caches subfolder by using a hard-coded string, but how can I set the file that NSUserDefaults saves to?

In a bundled application, it's set by the bundle ID, in Info.plist. But how can I set the bundle ID for a set of command line tools, which don't have an Info.plist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an NSUserDefaults instance with `+alloc` & `-init`, instead of using `+standardUserDefaults`. A user defaults instance that's created this way won't be created with a defaults domain corresponding to the main bundle ID, so you need to use the [`-addSuiteNamed:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/addSuiteNamed%3a) method to manually add a defaults domain to it.

(**Update**) Sorry, my bad! Suites are volatile, not persistent - useful for tools that need to read a shared set of defaults, not so much for an application that wants to *set* a default value. For the latter, have a look at [`-setPersistentDomain:forName:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setPersistentDomain%3aforName%3a). The keys in the domain dictionary define what keys belong to the named defaults domain, and the values supply their default values.

Here's a short example, that should create ~/Library/Defaults/com.shermpendley.DefaultsTest.plist, and store the listed key/value pair in it:

```c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] init];
    [defaults setPersistentDomain:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Hello" forKey:@"World"] forName:@"com.shermpendley.DefaultsTest"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    [defaults release];

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That looks promising. How do I set values, then? setObject:forKey:/synchronize doesn't seem to save my value anywhere on the system.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I forgot that suites are basically read-only. I've added a link to another method that creates domains that *do* synch - and tested it to verify that. :-)

Comment: Nevermind, figured that out: `CFPreferencesSetValue( (CFStringRef)key, (CFPropertyListRef)value, (CFStringRef)domain, kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, kCFPreferencesAnyHost);`

Comment: Ha! Funny timing. Thanks, though. :)

Comment: I think you were right the first time; it looks like setPersistentDomain sets the key-values, not the defaults. So I'd have to read the domain every time. The combination of addSuiteNamed: for reading and `CFPreferencesSetValue` for writing seems to meet my needs perfectly.

Comment: or just like use: `let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "com.words.talk2word")`,it's work for me.